# How can I build a function that specifies the argument for another function?

Tags: r, function, regression

I am trying to search for the optimal multiple regression model using different stepwise search methods - backward, forward or exhaustive. I wrote the following function, but couldn't get it to work.

```
cv <- function(stepwise) {
  num_folds = 5
  num_vars  = 11
  set.seed(1)
  folds = caret::createFolds(mtcars$mpg, k = num_folds)
  fold_error = matrix(0, nrow = num_folds, ncol = num_vars, 
                      dimnames = list(paste(1:num_folds), paste(1:num_vars)))

  for(j in 1:num_folds) {

    train_fold    = mtcars[-folds[[j]], ]
    validate_fold = mtcars[ folds[[j]], ]


    best_fit = regsubsets(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, nvmax = 10, method = stepwise)

    for (i in 1:num_vars) {

      pred = predict(best_fit, validate_fold, id = i)

      fold_error[j, i] = rmse(actual = validate_fold$mpg,
                              predicted = pred)
    }

  }

  cv_error = apply(fold_error, 2, mean)

  par(mfrow=c(1,1))
  plot(cv_error, type = 'l')
  cv_min = which.min(cv_error)
  points(cv_min, cv_error[cv_min], col = "red", cex = 2, pch = 20)

}

cv("backward")
```

The error returned is

> Error in pmatch(method[1], c("exhaustive", "backward", "forward", "seqrep"),  : 
>     object 'stepwise' not found

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Your code looks fine... are you sure?

Comment: @QAsena It does indeed expect a string. `stepwise` is OP's argument name for the `cv` function. `cv("backward")` is equivalent to `cv(stepwise = "backward")`, and `"backward"` is a string.

Comment: @Gregor quite true, just noticed that...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error... if I change the data to built-in data, `cv <- function(stepwise) {
  best_fit = regsubsets(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, nvmax = 10, method = stepwise) 
}`, it works just fine. Please make sure you don't have any typos, like `"backwards"` instead of `"backward"`, and that the definition of the function has been run as-is.

Comment: yeah, works for me too using `iris` dataset

Comment: Actually I simplified the above code... the actual code is the following. I changed it, based on the mtcar dataset:

Comment: cv <- function(stepwise) {
  num_folds = 5
  num_vars  = 11
  set.seed(1)
  folds = caret::createFolds(mtcars$mpg, k = num_folds)
  fold_error = matrix(0, nrow = num_folds, ncol = num_vars, 
                      dimnames = list(paste(1:num_folds), paste(1:num_vars)))
  
  for(j in 1:num_folds) {
    
    train_fold    = mtcars[-folds[[j]], ]
    validate_fold = mtcars[ folds[[j]], ]

Comment: best_fit = regsubsets(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, nvmax = 10, method = stepwise)
    
    for (i in 1:num_vars) {
      
      pred = predict(best_fit, validate_fold, id = i)
      
      fold_error[j, i] = rmse(actual = validate_fold$mpg,
                              predicted = pred)
    }
    
  }


}

Comment: When I run your new code (in the question--ignoring code in comments) the `regsubsets` line works fine. I get a different error later when you run `predict` on `best_fit`: `no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "regsubsets"`. This is expected since `regsubsets` doesn't return a model object, so there's nothing to predict on. (See `?regsubsets`, *"The model search does not actually fit each model"*). Instead, you should presumable fit the "best" model with `lm`.